# Como mostrar la cantidad de elementos repetidos de una tabla y compararlas con otras C# SQL WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

He logrado mostrar como unico dato el de mayor repeticion y tambien ordenarlo (cambiando el while por el if) pero me genera columnas vacias en el datagrid y no se como crear una nueva columna mediante codigo c# para que haga el conteo

```
 public List<eDenuncia> MayorxDepartamento() //ACA LE ESTOY IMPLEMENTANDO LA PARTE DE CONTAR LA HEUVADA
    {
        try
        {
            List<eDenuncia> IsDenuncia = new List<eDenuncia>();
            DateTime d;
            eDenuncia objDenuncia = null;
            SqlConnection con = db.ConectaDb();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("select Departamento, COUNT(*) as cantidad from Tabla_Denuncia GROUP BY Departamento ORDER BY cantidad DESC"), con);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                objDenuncia = new eDenuncia();

                objDenuncia.Departamento = (string)reader["Departamento"];

                IsDenuncia.Add(objDenuncia);
            }
            reader.Close();
            return IsDenuncia;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;

        }
        finally
        {
            db.DesconectaDb();
        }

    }
```

---

estuve intentando y no lo he logrado aun. Si resulta en Sql, mas no en codigo.

```
 public eDenuncia DepartamentosConMayorCasos( )
    {
        try
        {
            eDenuncia denuncia = null;
            SqlConnection con = db.ConectaDb();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Departamento, COUNT(*) as cantidad from Tabla_Denuncia GROUP BY DepartamentoORDER BY cantidad DESC", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {

                denuncia = new eDenuncia();
                denuncia.Departamento = (string)reader["Departamento"];
                //denuncia = Convert.ToString(reader["cantidad"]);


            }
            reader.Close();
            return denuncia;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;

        }
        finally
        {
            db.DesconectaDb();
        }

    }
```

se que tengo muchos errores, debido a que no domino muy bien las funciones en codigo de Sql. Quiero que el valor se retorne para mostrarlo con un MessageBox.Show

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar el `group by` de `sql` para contar en base a una columna, entonces puede definir

```
select Departamento, COUNT(*) as cantidad 
from Tabla_Denuncia
GROUP BY Departamento
ORDER BY cantidad DESC
```

Entonces tendras primero el registro que busca

Desde codigo si quiere solo un registro usarias

```
string connstring = "connection string";  
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) {  
    cn.Open();  

    string sql = @"select Departamento, COUNT(*) as cantidad 
                   from Tabla_Denuncia
                    GROUP BY Departamento
                    ORDER BY cantidad DESC";  
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);  

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

    if (reader.Read())  
    {  
        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["Departamento"]);  
        TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(reader["cantidad"]);   
    }  

}
```

Comment: Hola, estuve intentando y no lo he logrado aun. Si me resulta en Sql, mas no en codigo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. estoy comenzando a tener idea del funcionamiento.

Comment: pero que probema se presenta en el codigo? algun mensaje de error

Comment: Hola, la manera en la que me funciono fue creando un datagrid, pero me muestra columnas vacias(en donde estaban los demas datos) los cuales nose como eliminar.

Comment: podrias definir las columnas en diseño indicando con que dato del datasource mapea, es cuestion de aprender a usar el datagrid

Comment: Acabo de editarlo, voy a ver las funciones del datagrid para poder eliminar las columnas vacias